# not able to use webgraph command in nutch 1.2

Tags: nutch

I am quite new to nutch . Thing is I have crawled a site successfully using nutch 1.2 .Now using cygwin I am working on crawldb and segments . Problem is when I am using webgraphdb command it is showing "Error: Could not find or load main class WebGraph". Please suggest me that what I need to do to use this command properly.